# Bundle not working with rbenv

Tags: ruby, bundler, rbenv

I'm trying to use bundler with rbenv. I has been working until today. The only thing I may have done to break it was `gem pristine --all` or `gem cleanup` ? When trying to install bundler i get the following error.

```
Antarrs-MacBook-Pro:some-app antarrbyrd$ sudo gem install bundler
Password:
Bundler gave the error "Could not find mail-2.5.4 in any of the sources" while processing "/Users/antarrbyrd/dev/some-app/Gemfile". Perhaps you forgot to run "bundle install"?
Successfully installed bundler-1.7.12
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.7.12
Done installing documentation for bundler after 3 seconds
1 gem installed
Antarrs-MacBook-Pro:some-app antarrbyrd$ bundle install
/Users/antarrbyrd/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0) among 8 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/antarrbyrd/.gem', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /Users/antarrbyrd/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/antarrbyrd/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

when i do `rbenv rehash` or `rbenv bundler on` it get this error

```
Bundler gave the error "Could not find mail-2.5.4 in any of the sources" while processing "/Users/antarrbyrd/dev/some-app/Gemfile". Perhaps you forgot to run "bundle install"?
```

~/.bash_profile

```
export BUNDLER_EDITOR=atom
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/android-sdk/build-tools/21.1.2
export HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN=...

export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi

# Allow local Gem Managment 
# export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem"
# export GEM_PATH="$HOME/.gem"
# export PATH="$HOME/.gem/bin:$PATH"
```

`gem env`

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.2 (2014-05-08 patchlevel 95) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/antarrbyrd/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
     - /Users/antarrbyrd/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "-n/usr/local/bin"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin
     - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec
     - /Users/antarrbyrd/.gem/bin
     - /usr/local/var/rbenv/shims
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/local/var/rbenv/shims
     - /Users/antarrbyrd/.rbenv/bin
     - /Users/antarrbyrd/.rbenv/shims
     - /Users/antarrbyrd/.gem/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/android-sdk/build-tools/21.1.2
```

***update***

I reinstalled rbenv via brew and now I get the following error when running bundle install.

```
The `bundle' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.1.5
```

***response to Joel***

```
Antarrs-MacBook-Pro:myapp antarrbyrd$ command -v ruby
/usr/local/var/rbenv/shims/ruby
Antarrs-MacBook-Pro:myapp antarrbyrd$ command -v bundle
/usr/local/bin/bundle
Antarrs-MacBook-Pro:myapp antarrbyrd$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
Antarrs-MacBook-Pro:myapp antarrbyrd$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.7.12
Antarrs-MacBook-Pro:myapp antarrbyrd$
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Your installation is caught in a loop.

Change to a directory that is not your app, and that doesn't have a Gemfile.

Then do the usual `gem install bundle` (and use `sudo` if you need it)

Then change to your app directory, and do the usual `bundle install`.

Does that solve your issue?

If you need more help, can run these commands then paste the results in your question?

```
 $ command -v ruby
 $ command -v bundle
 $ ruby -v
 $ bundle -v
```

Look for any mismatch between the results and what you expect. This will help you track down what's happening. You may need to update your Gemfile Ruby version.

(Also, you may want to consider changing from `rbenv` to `chruby` because it's better IMHO with these kinds of path issues)

Comment: I've update the question with the output. It now gives me the following error  `Your Ruby version is 2.2.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2` , rbenv local is already set to 2.1.2

Comment: After reinstalling bundler  and rehash the error above was resolved.

Comment: after your solution, i've got : error: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)

Comment: this did not work for me. `gem install bundler` from @Vbp did work.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me.  What exactly is causing the loop though?

Comment: I have to run mine as `bundle exec rake test` to pick up the correct paths and load correctly.

Comment: What should we do if we get `Could not find 'bundler' (2.3.0)` but `bundle -v` returns `Bundler version 2.3.0`?

Answer (score 42):

I got:

```
rbenv: bundle: command not found

The `bundle' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.3.0
```

after upgrade to Ruby 2.3.1

and it's solved by:

```
gem install rails
```

from working folder

Comment: `gem install rails` was what I was missing, thank you

Comment: You just need to re-install `bundler` after upgrading your Ruby version using `rbenv`. `rbenv` keeps your gems containerized by each version of Ruby. So you need to do `gem install bundler` and you should be good to go.

Comment: should be `gem install bundler` instead of `gem install rails`... not everyone would be working with rails

Answer (score 39):

```
gem install bundler
```

You need to reinstall bundler for each version of Ruby you use.

Reference: [github issue](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/285#issuecomment-11843413)

Answer (score 17):

Try to use:

> bin/bundle

instead of

> bundle

Comment: This one worked as it picked the local ruby version.

Answer (score 16):

I had the exact same issue and tried absolutely everything here and all over internet but the command that finally worked for me was:

```
gem update --system
```

Comment: This worked for me too with a rbenv local install not recognising cocoapods. This fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

If none of the other solutions work for you try this.

For some reason I could not install bundler on specific ruby versions, thus reinstalling bundler did nothing for me.

However I noticed how `rbenv whence bundle` specified that bundle was active in some ruby versions, but not others. If you look under the path for the gem without bundler (for me this was `~/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/`) you will notice that it is not there.  However under other versions that whence can recognise you will see the executable is there (for me it was there under `~/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/bundle`).

Just copy the executable over from the working ruby version to the one that is broken. Then at the top of the file you will notice sha-bang is set to the other ruby version (for me this was `#!/Users/myuser/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/ruby`).  Change the version path to the ruby version you want to fix and then it will all magically start working.

Comment: This was the only working solution for me. I don’t like that it works, but I appreciate your writing it up. I’d like to know why rbenv isn’t doing what it’s supposed to do? I’ve lost enough time however.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what worked for me with a legacy project:

1. Set the proper ruby version via rbenv

```
    $ cd YOUR_PROJECT_DIRECTORY
    $ rbenv install 2.1.0
    $ rbenv local 2.1.0
```

2. If you still get an error when installing bundle, look for a PATH warning:

```
    $ gem install bundle
    WARNING:  You don't have /Users/lex/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin in your PATH,
          gem executables will not run.
    Successfully installed bundle-0.0.1
    1 gem installed
```

3. Update your PATH:

```
    $ PATH=/Users/lex/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/bin:$PATH
```

4. Try again:

```
    $ bundle install
    Fetching: bundler-1.11.2.gem (100%)
    HTTP GET https://bundler.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
    HTTP 200 OK
    Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/
    . . .
```

Using sudo to install gems is generally not what you want to do.

Comment: That first step, of specifying the local (or global) version of ruby you want to use is critical, otherwise there is a loop, notwithstanding what is in your .ruby-version file

Answer (score 3):

For installing bundler with `Ruby` less than `2.3.0` use following command

```
gem install bundler -v '< 2'
```

Comment: none of the solution worked for me but this one.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting ruby globally

```
rbenv global 2.3.1
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issue today. My issue was fixed as follows:

```
system dependencies
- rvenv
- ruby 2.5.0
- rails 5.1.6
```

check bundler version in Gemfile.lock

```
BUNDLED WITH
  1.17.3
```

install specific version of bundler

```
$ gem install bundler -v 1.17.3
Fetching bundler-1.17.3.gem
Successfully installed bundler-1.17.3
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.17.3
Done installing documentation for bundler after 3 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Hope this will help somebody.

Answer (score 2):

I recently bumped my ruby version from `2.7.5` to `2.7.6`.

Doing `sudo gem install cocoapods` after installing the new ruby version did the trick.!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue running Guard with Foreman.
My original command to run it was:

```
bundle exec foreman run guard -c
```

This gave me these errors:

```
11:07:52 - INFO - Run all
11:07:52 - INFO - Running all specs
/Users/MyUser/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0) among 146 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/MyUser/devel/o2/vesta/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0', execute `gem env` for more information
        from /Users/MyUser/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
        from /Users/MyUser/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
        from /Users/MyUser/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

The simple fix was to not use `bundle exec` with foreman but to use it against guard. e.g.

```
foreman run bundle exec guard -c
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

None of the provided answers worked for me, so I had to completely uninstall `rbenv` and everything related to Ruby and then just install Ruby 2.7.1 with Homebrew; `brew install ruby`.

Comment: To the extent that this is an answer, it's a bad answer. `brew install ruby` installs ruby globally with no control over the version and using ruby with global gems will cause issues with projects that use bundler / Gemfiles